# lubuntu completely ignoring ldap setup. Followed guide, no contact with ldap server

Tags: lubuntu, users, authentication, ldap, pam

We have LDAP authentication working on every other server and lxc container in our enterprise, but when we try and have a brand spankin new Lubuntu 14.04 installation do the same, it's completely flipping us the bird.

I followed the directions we used on everything else very closely: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication

I can see ldap listed in `/etc/nssswtich.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

and we've run `pam-auth-update`. Our `/etc/ldap.conf` looks just fine too. All of the `/etc/pam.d/common-*` have ldap listed... As an act of desperation, pulled all the `common-*` files from one of our working servers and tossed them this box to no avail. When we do an `id some.ldapuser` we get this:

```
bananapi@lemaker:~$ sudo id jonathan.fisher
id: jonathan.fisher: no such user
```

I really have no idea what else to check. We've done tcpdumps to the LDAP server and it's not even reaching out and contacting it. `auth.log` doesn't help any and there's nothing in `syslog`. What the deuce is going on?

Comment: Does `getent passwd` show anything from LDAP? Could you try using `nslcd`, `libpam-ldapd` and `libnss-ldapd` (instead of `libnss-ldap` and `libpam-ldap`)? With `nslcd`, you will have to edit `/etc/nslcd.conf` to configure LDAP authentication.

Comment: `getent passwd jonathan.fisher` returns nothing. I'll do some googling on the second setup, but the info is much more sparse. 

I feel like I'm missing a really simple switch somewhere... this is incredibly aggravating.

Comment: Is there a way to turn on more logging in pam?